# Return data from Database where data is repeated

Tags: php, mysql, return

sorry to bother you guys, but been trying everything i could to get some data from database, and all the time it show's me blank, so i'm getting blank flashes as well :)

So what i need to to is,

[image: database data]

as you see on the pic, i have a column ownerId with repeated data, this is ok, i work's like that, now what i want extract from the database is to show the itemId and count where ownerId = ?.

So have my query as bellow.

```
<table id="zctb" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item ID</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<?php   
$sql = "SELECT ownerId, itemId, count from user_item where ownerId = :editid";
$query = $dbh2 -> prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':editid',$editid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$cnt=1; 

if($query->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($results as $result){               
?>  
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->item_name);?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->itemId);?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->count);?></td>
            </tr>
<?php 
        $cnt=$cnt+1; 
    }
} 
?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

but this don't return anything not even not data found on the table.

any idea?

Comment: did you check , if there is something in $editid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check if you have a value in the variable $editid

2) you have an error in iterating over an array:
foreach ($results as $result) // you don't have a $results variable

Comment: Yes , with your answer i fix the issue.

need to be like this

<?php  
        $sql = "SELECT itemId, count from user_item where ownerId = :editid";
        $query = $dbh2 -> prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':editid',$editid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $query->execute();
  $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $cnt=1; 
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{    ?>